# Parse Anypic multi languages

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

does anyone know how to get multi languages by using Parse Anypic? Is there a languages file to change? Then via a setting menu one user can change the languages, or the language is shown according to the mobile language.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can implement localization by yourself. You may do it by following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014) which I think is a good starting point.